# reactjs not recognizing propTypes of a prop

Tags: reactjs, components

Suppose I have a React component that has propTypes.

```
Page.propTypes = {
 rawItems: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

I put the following line of code in to one of my functions

```
 if (rawItems === React.PropTypes.string.isRequired)
```

Well...the 'if' returned false!! How can that be? So I played around a bit with different components and discovered that the same code used for a regular component does indeed return true. Its when I was calling this type of code for a stateless component that it returned false.

Any clues why that would be? Any other way to dynamically figure out the prop type of a prop other than doing that if stmt above?

Thank you

Comment: React throws an error if the type is different than what is passed in. You should assume its a string and expect an error to be called if it isn't a string.

Comment: `rawItems` is a prop of your component, of type string, so it won't equal `React.PropTypes.string.isRequired`, however, have you tried seeing if `Page.propTypes.rawItems === React.PropTypes.string.isRequired`?